# Do not select menuItem on icon click in material ui select

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am making a dropdown with functionality of deleting a menu but when i click on icon in menu item menu item also get selected how to prevent this default behaviour
heres my code

```
{
                    dropdowns.categories && dropdowns.categories.map((data, index) => {
                      return <MenuItem
                        key={index}
                        className="d-flex justify-content-between"
                        style={{ width: "170px" }}
                        value={data}>
                        {data}
                        <IconButton
                          style={{ position: "absolute", right: "0px" }}
                          onClick={() => deleteItem(data, "categories")}
                          className="icon-button">
                          <i className="fa fa-trash"></i>
                        </IconButton>
                      </MenuItem>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

> The stopPropagation() method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

```
onClick={event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    deleteItem(data, "categories");
}
```